# Extract string from text file with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a text file called `.env` like this:

```
SOME_VAR="value"
SOME_VAR_2="value2"
NODE_ENV="staging"
SOME_VAR_3="value3"
```

I need to extract the string in between `"` and `"` where the lines begin with `NODE_ENV=`

In other words, I need the string `staging` from that file. Then I need to use a command like.

Right now I have this:

```
git checkout $(cat .environment)
```

Where `.environment` is a file with a single value `staging`, so with that command I got:

```
git checkout $(cat .environment)
```

but now I need what I said before, to extract the value from a file with multiple lines in the mentioned format.

I tried with `sed` but I'm not sure how to use it:

```
sed -r '/NODE_ENV.*/I!d;s/.*:.(.*).}$/\1/' .env
```

but that's:

```
NODE_ENV="staging"
```

and what I need is to get:

```
staging
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is looking for a `:` character, but there's no `:` in the file. You should be looking for `="..."` and use the capture group to match what's between the `"`.

```
sed -n -r '/NODE_ENV/s/.*="(.*)"/\1/p' .env
```

Use the `-n` option to disable default printing, then append `p` to the command to print that matching line after the substitution.

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited the question with a new (incorrect) regex

Comment: I wish you would roll back the edit so my answer would make more sense.

Comment: Done, rollback to original regex. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep to extract this value:

```
grep -Po '(?<=NODE_ENV=")[^"]*' .env
```

output will be:

```
staging
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine some simple commands:

```
grep NODE_ENV .env | sed -E 's/.*"(.*)"/\1/'
```